# Syntastic error symbols are offsetting my code

Tags: vim, syntastic

```
somecode();
somecode();
somecode();
```

But if syntastic finds and error it will display the error sign at that line like this

```
      somecode();
   >> somecode()
      somecode();
```

The problem is that everything will get a bit indented because there was no space for the error sign.

How would I fix this? Is it possible to reserve more space for the `sign`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you are disturbed by the repetitive swap of the display of the sign column, each time an error appears, then disappears?

I tried to solve this problem before, but without any real good solution; the `sign` feature lacks some better flexibility, to my point of view.

The workaround I found to avoid constant code shifting was to add a custom transparent sign on the first line of a file, so as the column sign never disappears, and add this trick to an autocommand to make it automatic:

```
sign define transparent_sign
augroup SignColFixAu
    au!
    au BufReadPost *.c,*.cc,*.h,*.cpp,*.hh,*.py,*.js,*.php exe "sign place 1111 name=transparent_sign line=1 file=".@%
augroup end
```

Of course, in the code above you have to customize the file pattern to your liking.